# Use of Name in Doctype Declarations in XML

Tags: xml, dtd

I tried internal and external DTD's both with a name different than the root element name , it still Works!.

Its about the value of "Name" in the tag below -

```
<DOCTYPE Name SYSTEM "Couple.dtd">
```

What's the use of this "Name" then?

1)Internal DTD

```
<!DOCTYPE  SampleDocType[
<!ELEMENT Neighbours (Couple, Couple) >
<!ELEMENT Couple (Name, Name) >
<!ELEMENT Name ( Vorname, Nachname, Geschlecht) >
<!ELEMENT Vorname (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT Nachname (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT Geschlecht (#PCDATA) >
]>

<Couple>

    <Name>

        <Vorname>Marie</Vorname>

        <Nachname>M&#252;ller</Nachname>

        <Geschlecht>&#61;</Geschlecht>

    </Name>

    <Name>


        <Vorname>Klaus</Vorname>

        <Nachname>M&#xfc;ller</Nachname>

        <Geschlecht>♂</Geschlecht>

    </Name>

</Couple>
```

2)External DTD

```
<!DOCTYPE SampleDocType SYSTEM "Couple.dtd" >

<Couple>

<Name>

 <Vorname>Marie</Vorname>

 <Nachname>M&#252;ller</Nachname>

 <Geschlecht>&#61;</Geschlecht>

</Name>

<Name>


 <Vorname>Klaus</Vorname>

 <Nachname>M&#xfc;ller</Nachname>

 <Geschlecht>♂</Geschlecht>

</Name>

</Couple>
```

external DTD file

```
<!ELEMENT Neighbours ( Couple, Couple) >
<!ELEMENT Couple (Name, Name) >
<!ELEMENT Name ( Vorname, Nachname, Geschlecht) >
<!ELEMENT Vorname (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT Nachname (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT Geschlecht (#PCDATA) >
```

**Note** - I am using XMLtools plugin in Notepad++ for validation.

Comment: What does "it still works" mean here?

Comment: its said that the DOCTYPE "name" MUST match root element name, which I did NOT follow. But my document still passes validation.

Comment: A validator that does not enforce the validity constraint "Root Element Type" (quoted below by Daniel Haley) is not a conforming XML validator.  That does not, of course, answer your question (what use is the name in the document type declaration?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask *What's the use of "Name" in ... `<!DOCTYPE Name SYSTEM "Couple.dtd">`?*

Like all intentional redundancies, the Name in the XML document type declaration allows for consistency checking.  In SGML (from which XML inherited the syntax of the declaration) the checking may be more important, since the document type declaration and the start-tag of the document's outermost element may be in different files or entities.  Since XML requires that the document type declaration (if present) be in the same data stream as the tags of the document's outermost element, there is less obvious need for the redundancy in XML, and it would not be too far off to say that the name is retained for compatibility with SGML.

Comment: This makes sense! :) . However , what do you exactly mean by consistency checking ? Now , I think in SGML - If the doctype declaration is in a different file &  if the Name in DOCTYPE declaration is not same as root element name ; it won't even be possible to validate...How would the parser know which DTD to use , and where is it located?right?

Answer (score 2):

Per the spec ([1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-doctypedecl) and [1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#dt-doctype)):

> The Name in the document type declaration MUST match the element type
>   of the root element.

If your tool is not reporting this as an error, I believe it is the fault of the tool.

Comment: guess so.Any easy utility to check Validity of XML against DTD's and XSD's?

Comment: The XML tools plugin in Notepad++ uses libxml2. There seems to be something wrong with that plugin's "Validate Now" command. Running xmllint (the command line tool that comes with libxml2) on the XML samples, with the `--valid` option, produces the expected error message: **element Couple: validity error : root and DTD name do not match 'Couple' and 'SampleDocType'**.